# What happens to the transaction in this SQL if it's not committed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, transactions

If I have the following SQL:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT val
FROM myTable
```

and don't follow it up with a commit, what happens with the TRANSACTION? Does it depend upon the context/scope that it was executed (e.g. in a proc, in mgt studio)?

Is there some place to see if there are transactions open that have not been committed/rolled back in a database?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stays open until the connection closes. When the connection is closed, the transaction is rolled back.

Current transactions can be seen in [sys.dm_tran_active_transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174302.aspx) and [sys.dm_tran_database_transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186957.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Locks are not released for the objects used in the transaction and changes are only visible to that connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use following command to check for all open transactions in database:

```
DBCC CHECKTRAN
```